# Submit pull request for changes to packages installed via "go get"

Tags: git, github, go

I have a package I installed via `go get github.com/<other_user>/<repository>`. It was missing some features, so I have been working with the original author to add them to the package.

I made the changes to my local copy and committed them. Then I realized: derp, I don't have authorization to `git push` these changes.

Is there a way for me to salvage my changes and somehow submit a pull request to him? Or do I have to lose all my changes, fork his repository, re-implement my changes, and then submit a pull request?

And no matter what I do, is there a way for me to retain the ability to do this command?

```
go get -u <original_repository>
```

Or do I have to just become a full-time contributor and continually update my fork with his repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fork the repo in GitHub, then add your fork as a remote in your working copy under a name other than origin, e.g. `git remote add myfork git@github.org...`. You can push your changes to your fork (`git push myfork`), then open a PR from your fork to the original.

Explicitly, the commands would something like this after you fork the original to your own account:

```
git remote add myfork https://github.com/<your_username>/<repository>.git
git push myfork
```

After which, you can submit the PR to the original. If your PR is accepted, you can then run these commands:

```
git remote remove myfork
git rebase master
git pull origin master
```

You can then delete your fork from your GitHub account. After which, `go get -u` will function as normal.

Any time you need to make new changes to the package, you can repeat this process.

Comment: `go get` doesn't fetch anything if it exists locally. Running `go get -u` will call `git pull --ff-only`, but it will never change your remote tracking branch.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if ff-only would work with committed local changes then. Only one way to find out for sure!

Comment: If course it won't work, because you can't fast-forward if there's changes. It will also fail if you don't have tracking info for your local branch (which is default when making a branch and pushing it to a remote), though even if you did it would still do nothing, because you're remote branch is the same thing you just pushed!

Comment: He didn't say anything about making a branch, so he'll still be on the same branch that was originally checked out (master), with one additional commit, which will have been pushed to a secondary remote, but not the remote tracked by the branch. So a fast forward (and therefore `go get -u`, according to @JimB earlier comment), wouldn't work without a clean checkout from origin. Could change it to track the fork, and then keep the fork up to date from its upstream, but the import path would be misleading at that point.